# Jquery Graphical Login Report

Tags: jquery-ui, cakephp, jquery-plugins

I need to show a bar char for user login into the sites of the month in bar chart 
   Can u please suggest me a jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

Highs charts is a nice, well documented, plugin.
Providing jQuery support as well.
http://www.highcharts.com/